# eclipse+pydev how to rename module?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm using eclipse + pydev. I want to refactor and change the name of my module. I clicked on my module in the package explorer, but no refactoring (other than 'rename') in the context menu. Similarly, the refactoring on the top navigation menu is greyed out.

So how do i change my module name and have it reflected across my project.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is still not properly integrated in the pydev package explorer, so, for now, you have to find a place that uses the module you want in the code and rename that reference in the editor (you don't need to report that as a bug as that's already known and should be fixed soon).

Comment: Has this been added? I can't seem to find it.  EDIT: Using LiClipse.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this still hasn't been added so far. Unfortunately the refactoring hasn't received much attention lately. Please create a ticket for that in https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/

Answer (score 1):

Did you try rename? it seems to work in other language plugins.(make sure to right click on the module)

Comment: Rename works now for me as of posting. "Move" is broken though and doesn't update references. Just use rename to refactor.